# Why won't Google use my meta description?

Tags: seo, google-search, meta-tags

I have an issue with my website: Google isn’t using my meta description, instead it’s using the content of the web page and I’m really confused.

Reason I’m confused is because I have checked and I don’t have duplicate page titles, description nor keywords, neither do I have any robots.txt for my website.
My page title, description and keyword is unique, and page description is about 150 characters.

I have my site in Google Webmaster Tools and I checked for errors, but found none.

So I really don’t know why Google Search isn’t using my meta description.

Comment: I actually searched for what is in my title and description on google search and my site did not show up on Google, until i typed text that are in web page content.

Comment: The META description is not used to index your site. It is only used in the SERPs, unless other page text is deemed more relevant.

Comment: Please don’t [cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27966537/1591669).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design and is how Google works.

It does not necessarily use the meta description in the SERPs if it thinks other text on the page is more relevant to what the user has searched for.

Comment: Isn't there something i can do about that ?

Comment: Unfortunately not, unless perhaps your META description does not already relate directly to the on-page content? Are you suggesting that the snippet that Google is displaying is wholly inaccurate? Usually it is related to what the user has searched for, highlighting words in the content. The snippet displayed in the SERPs will often change depending on the search phrase.

Comment: For Example: my title contains - "Buy History books". and then my  webpage content contains " get discount of Alexandra books"... And then if i search "buy history books" on google, Google doesn't show my website in the result even to many pages, but when i type any word in the content...Like discount of alexandra books" ..Woalla Google displays it !

Comment: And then thats my problem, because most users will rather type in "buy History books" on their browser than a particular Author's book

Comment: To be honest "Buy history books" is very generic (almost spam-like) so it is not surprising your site is going to struggle getting indexed for those keywords - it's very competitive. But are users really going to search for something vague like "buy history books", rather than the specific item they are searching for?

Comment: ...but also, if the TITLE does not relate directly to the page content (ie. you're not discussing "buying history books" in the general sense) it's not going to carry the _weight_ you hope it will.

Comment: @HtmlTosin For the record. The description meta-tag is indexed, but little to zero weight is given to the words contained within it. But it is used for matching. You can do a site: search and Google will likely use the tag. But for user searches w3d is right. Google will return the most relevant match. However, your description meta-tag, if done well, should match most of the time. It should contain your most important keywords (that people actually use) and some long-tail keywords. It sounds like all you need to do really is tune it up a little to make it more relevant.

Answer (score 2):

<sub>(My answer from your [cross-posted (and now closed) question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27966537/1591669).)</sub>

Google shows your `meta`-`description` if they think it’s useful for the searching user.

See [Google’s documentation](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35624?hl=en#1) (bold emphasis mine):

> Google will **sometimes** use the meta description of a page in search results snippets, if we think it gives users a more accurate description than would be possible purely from the on-page content.