# Wrong Meta Description is showing at Google SERP

Tags: seo, google-search-console

I am facing a problem with Meta Description. I have given a Meta Description but Google index & showing another page's Meta Description at SERP for my example.com main domain. Meta Title is right.

I also request to Google for re-index through Fetch as Google also but for some days no changes showed.

At this time is there any perfect solution. or Will I update again Meta Tags?

Comment: We get these questions a lot. Have you tied the site: search directive? This will show your meta description as Google has it. Otherwise the result will depend on the search query. What searches are you using? If you find the meta description is still wrong using the site: directive, then you will just have to wait. Google makes mistakes from time to time.

Comment: It's showing more then four months

Comment: Our community already answer this question two times, checkout [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/76125/why-wont-google-use-my-meta-description) and [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15973/does-google-use-the-meta-description-tag-for-description-of-page).

Answer (score 0):

This URL: https://www.firstscribe.com/google-change-title-description-search-results/ states

```
Remember what Google's ultimate goal is: 
to provide the most relevant search results possible for any given search query.
```

This means that if your meta description doesn't contain at least a few important keywords relevant to the site, then the search engines will likely scan your page to try to guess a good description.

For example, if your site is on apples and oranges and your meta description is:

```
Check out our fruits
```

Then Google might change it to the first sentence of your website:

```
Welcome to our fruit site.
```

However, if in your description you put in:

```
Apples, Oranges, and other fruits are discussed here
```

then Google might accept it, especially if guests are looking for apples and/or oranges just because the keywords are in the meta description as well as in the paragraphs of your site.