# Does using an open graph description that duplicates the meta description prevent Google from using the description in the search results?

Tags: google, meta-description, open-graph-protocol

I have a site which is using both an OpenGraph meta description property:

```
<meta property="og:description"
```

...as well a bog standard Meta description property:

```
<meta name="description" content=
```

The meta descriptions are exactly the same and the meta description isn't displaying correctly in Google. There is currently no meta tag implemented blocking Google from the OpenGraph dup description:

```
<meta name="robots" content="NOODP">
```

There could be a number of reasons why this is happening (tag may not be descriptive enough, tag may be too similar to others on the site) but I'm still new to this, and I can't find an exact categorical 'no' answer...

So, does anyone have experience of this - could it be **one** of the reasons why it's not displaying correctly - because there is technically duplicate meta's on the page and OpenGraph isn't blocked to the engine? ..and so is the best implementation to have only one, or block the search engine from seeing the open graph property.

Comment: In 2010 Google used to use the meta description in the search results 95% of the time.   Now days it uses it about 10% of the time and only if the keywords in it are a very good match.   It's just how Google is right now. See also [Why won't Google use my meta description?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/76125/why-wont-google-use-my-meta-description)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Stephen!! I'm in SEO and I couldn't agree more, that is the state of Search atm. But my query is specific in relation to anyone's experience with how Google interacts with Opengraph tags and their implementation. Perhaps someone has tested this.