# Google results shows two different versions of my site with different snippet, how do i make it so its the same snippet?

Tags: seo, meta-tags, meta-description

My website shows up on google with two different ways.For example say this is my site megaexample.com

When I search example in google my shows up with this snippet "good snippet text" from my meta:description but when I search megaexample my site shows up with this snippet "bad snippet text" which google took from my cookies not from my meta:description.

Now I have already changed my cookies but this result is still there after a month.

What do I have to do to have the meta:description show up for both results?
edit:added images of google snippet, its in greek.
Anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?
[image]

Comment: [Why won't Google use my meta description?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/76125/17633)

Comment: Google doesn't show snippet text from cookies, I think you are mistaken.

Comment: I've never heard of Google indexing the content of cookies either.  Googlebot doesn't even accept cookies when it crawls.   I suspect that the "bad" text is somewhere else on your page as well.

Answer (score 1):

See how I solved exactly the same problem in 15 days :)
I had an url index by google twice and with different descriptions.
so I removed slahs at the end of the url and let google index my url again.
after google index my url I got an error in search console panel.
url not reachable.
than I add slahs at the end of my url again and let google know url problem is solved please check again.

all done after 3 days :)

and check this article :

https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2013/04/5-common-mistakes-with-relcanonical.html